# How do I fix setting an html element not accepting it's correctly formatted value?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

So what's happening is I'm trying to automate signing into a website. In the login page, it asks for an email. Using "GetElementById" and "SetAttribute" I am setting the inputs value to an email. However, for some reason, the website doesn't think that it's a valid email address. Although when you put it in manually it works fine. I have tried clicking on the element and then setting the attribute and things like that. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the way I'm currently setting the input value's value:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("i0116").SetAttribute("value", "example@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Using SetAttribute, use the InnerText property

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("i0116").InnerText = "example@gmail.com";
```

Comment: Glad I could help!